# How to remove varargs suggested variables in Netbeans 8?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, variadic-functions, netbeans-8

Consider the following Java method:

`Paths.get(String first, String... more)`

It is nice that you have access to the varargs *when needed*, however Netbeans 8, and earlier versions, **insist** that you will use at least one varargs element.

So assume you have the following:

```
String a = "";
String b = "";
```

Then you start typing `Paths.g`, you select the option, and it suddenly pops up with:

`Paths.get(a, b)`, while in reality you wanted to type `Paths.get(a)`.

Is there any way to tell Netbeans that when it encounters a varargs argument method, that I **do not** want to use the varargs in autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

No, in NetBeans 8.0.2 there is no such option. What it has nowadays is an option to ignore totally the arguments suggestion. You can go to Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion, select the Java language and deselect 'Guess Filled Method Arguments' option.